# Lua: shell.run('asdf','arg1','arg2') Arguments? Tagging?

Tags: lua, computercraft

What do the arguments do? How do I code a tag for shell.run('asdf') somewhere and link it to the shell.run('asdf') line?
The Code:

```
  turtle.dig()
  turtle.forward()
 -what api works with shell.run() here?-  <---------- Where I want tag.
  turtle.digUp()
  turtle.dig()
  turtle.turnLeft()
  turtle.dig()
  turtle.turnRight()
  turtle.up()
if turtle.detect() then
  shell.run('asdf')        <---------- What do I put to link it to tag.
else
  turtle.forward()
  turtle.turnLeft()
end
  while not turtle.detectDown() do
    turtle.dig()
    turtle.down()
  end
turtle.turnLeft()
turtle.forward()
turtle.forward()
turtle.turnLeft()
turtle.turnLeft()
```

Comment: This is not plain Lua. Please give context.

Comment: Looks like computercraft. http://www.computercraft.info/

Comment: its computercraft for a fact.

Answer (score 3):

`shell.run` runs a command, as if you had typed it into the command line. I think you are confusing it with `goto`, which is much different.

The arguments to `shell.run` are passed as arguments to the command line.

Ex. `shell.run("ls")` will run the `ls` command, and `shell.run("rm", "foo.txt")` will run `rm foo.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here make it a function:

```
  turtle.dig()
  turtle.forward()
  function tag() -- function

    turtle.digUp()
   turtle.dig()
   turtle.turnLeft()
   turtle.dig()
  turtle.turnRight()
   turtle.up()
if turtle.detect() then
 tag() -- running the function
 else
  turtle.forward()
  turtle.turnLeft()
 end
  while not turtle.detectDown() do
       turtle.dig()
    turtle.down()
  end
 turtle.turnLeft()
 turtle.forward()
 turtle.forward()
 turtle.turnLeft()
 turtle.turnLeft()
```